# How to retrieve interface for a class from a different assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

In WCF, it's common to put interfaces and implementation classes in a separate assemblies. I'm building a class that creates a WCF proxy class based on configuration (whether from services or serviceActivations in my web.config or from the Service attribute in an svc file). In my class, I want to retrieve the interfaces that are assignable from a service class - in the situation where the class and interface is in the same assembly, this is easy:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
if (type != null)
{
    var interfaces =
    Assembly.GetAssembly(type)
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsInterface && t.IsAssignableFrom(type));               
}
```

Short of using some brute force reflection solution by getting all assemblies (using CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) and finding interfaces that way, is there a prescribed method to get interfaces from a different (unknown) assembly?

Also, I know about using WCF discovery instead of doing this work myself - unfortunately, it is not an option in my situation.

Comment: i think you should look at MEF or Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a handy reflection method called "GetInterfaces()" that can provide this info:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(activation.Service);
if (type != null)
   Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
```